# HP scanners connected before driver installation in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, drivers, scanner

I am experiencing this problem with several HP scanners on Windows 7 in our Organization.

If the technician or the user mistakenly connected the scanner to the machine before installing the drivers, the scanner won't work. Sometimes the scanner is found the device manager under "imaging devices", but the scanning software says "No scanner was found". uninstalling the driver and reinstalling it does not solve the problem.

Is there a way to solve this problem without having to reformat the machine?

Comment: If you go into the device manager you can uninstall the driver, but check the box that says delete the driver also.  If this does not solve the problem another problem exists.  I would try a different USB cable.

Answer (score 0):

The Problem:-

Probably, You are using a wrong drivers for your scanner.

The Solutions:-

Solution 1 -> First check the scanner name and its model number and search for driver on the official website of HP. After search, you may find many drivers for same scanner with same model number. Choose appropriate driver according to your OS and architecture (eg:-x86 or x64).

Solution 2 -> If it fails, then you can try restoring your OS to the earlier time when you didn't experimented with your scanner and drivers then try installing the appropriate drivers again.

Final Solution -> If it also fails, then their is no another choice to backup your Data and then Reinstall the O.S. (eg:- Windows, Linux etc.) in the machine.

Comment: There is certainly no reason to reinstall the OS to get a scanner working.

Comment: I don't think this is the problem, since other machines use the same model of the scanner running on the same drivers, with no problems.

Comment: But, you have to try. Thinking is not a solution to any problem. If it doesn't work then nothing will be lost. If it will really don't work for you then try to include some more details such as scanner model no. or any other thing that you know and try to find out some more details. I think most persons would not be able to answer you problem with having enough details.